# SendSignedTransaction web3 v1.0 smart contract method call

Tags: parity, web3js-v1.x

Running parity node, connected to Kovan testnet.
Contract Address: 0x354Db5AE17b11fbc01A8a146B63506b1d90872E0

Using a nodejs app + web3 to send/sign transactions with the private key corresponding to this address : 
https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x02c52ceee9671b99152dff00172a53759d8b081a

which is non-empty.

With an instance of the contract, its method calls run fine, eg: 
    var response = await tokenContract.methods.awardToken(addressParser(address),1).send({from:Account.public})
    console.log(response)

Pulls up the parity ui signer in order to sign.  Transaction goes through fine.

However, I must sign and send this transaction using just web3 -- I eventually want to deploy this to an IoT device.  There will be no parity ui.

```
let tx = {}
tx.nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(Account.public)
tx.from = Account.public;
tx.to = tokenContract.options.address;
tx.data = tokenContract.methods.awardToken(addressParser(address),1).encodeABI();
// //tx.gas = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
tx.gas = 22888
```

which yields a tx object.

I have Account object containing the private/public key pair, from:

```
var Account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey);
```

But when I sign and send the signed transaction, I get insufficient gas from the sender's account:

```
let signedTx = await Account.signTransaction(tx, Account.privateKey);
console.log(signedTx)
```

> { messageHash: '0xaa18a8ce5eb123ce13ed1b64c0653b4846fc0303bfc3814da06d9ae92dd42f2a',
>     v: '0x78',
>     r: '0x0f04a9fb70676a7e47d9673399c9e2339ab425b53df389e19e68342e9cc9f56e',
>     s: '0x2adf857a27b95fe43fa69073b2d3ff40d5c7f963d04aa91afe6b388152e05746',
>     rawTransaction: '0xf8ab108609184e72a0008302710094354db5ae17b11fbc01a8a146b63506b1d90872e080b844ded2d0f4
>   000000000000000000000000db12813b2fd2651f11278218b4ebf69b7d1a8a7d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   0000000000000000000000178a00f04a9fb70676a7e47d9673399c9e2339ab425b53df389e19e68342e9cc9f56ea02adf857a27b9
>   5fe43fa69073b2d3ff40d5c7f963d04aa91afe6b388152e05746' }

```
var receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction);
console.log(receipt)
```

> Error: Returned error: Insufficient funds. The account you tried to send transaction from does not have e
>   nough funds. Required 114440000000000 and got: 0.

I must be missing something basic... web3.eth.defaultAccount = public key, which was derived from corresponding supplied private key, and there is a sufficient balance in the account ( verified using web3.eth.getBalance(Account.public)).

Parity, when receiving the rawtransaction is associating the signature with an entirely different publickey/wallet address (of 0 balance).

Comment: web3.eth.accounts.recoverTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction) showing different public key than what's expected.  there is no problem, im just doing something silly.  bbl

Comment: now i got the appropriate public address funded (derp), the Kovan gas required went up a ridiculous amount 
"Required 1393939200000000000 and got: 1000000000000000000."
Is Kovan being attacked atm?

Comment: it looks like your gas price is set super high, like to 1,000 gwei, when the standard is normally 20 gwei. Try lowering your gas price. Also your gas is set to 160,000 which is much higher than the 22888 you set it to in your example. Not sure if that's something you changed in debugging, or something a library changed, but those two things together are making the gas costs of the transaction very high.

Comment: I have the same problem ,
who can help ?

Comment: @陈东泽 if your problem is also that you can recoverTransaction to a different public key, it might be a private key format error. See me answering my own question at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/45646/possible-reason-for-insufficient-funds-for-gas-price-value?noredirect=1#comment53612_45646

Answer (score 0):

Apart from from a couple details you were missing, the most important thing you left out is to *serialize* the transaction. You can find a solution to all these issues in an answer I provided [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/55104/transaction-signing-fails-invalid-rlp-datarlpexpectedtobelist) (That one uses web3 0.xx, but that should not matter.)