# possible reason for insufficient funds for gas * price + value

Tags: web3js, web3-providers

I have been researching this whole day, but I have a web3 instance, (the Web3 is version 1.0.0)

```
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/<myKey>'));
```

Later I used it to sign a transaction (which is a call to a contract). I have

```
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiArray, contractAddr);
var func = contract.methods.myMethod('foo', 'bar')

var encodedFunc = func.encodeABI();

var tx = {
    from: ownerWallet,
    to: contractAddr,
    gas: web3.utils.toHex(1000000), //1m, also tried string '1000000'
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(20000000000), //20gwei, also tried string '20000000000'
    data: encodedFunc
}

//might just be unnecessary three lines
const account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(ownerPrivate)
console.log(account)
web3.eth.getBalance(ownerWallet).then(console.log)

const signed = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, ownerPrivate)
var trans = web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction)
```

Error is like,

```
Error: Returned error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value
```

Everything seems quite normal. What could be the issue?

Comment: gas and gasPrice definitely have to be wrapped in web3.toHex(), like gasPrice: web3.toHex(20000000000)

Comment: @NikitaFuchs, I tried. Still the same error. I modified my question to toHex too. Can there be other reasons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So... I figured out. The reason is Web3 takes the private key in `0xa0b1c2...` format. I used to use ethereumjs-tx package, which takes a private key in `const privateKey = new Buffer('a0b1c2...')` without `0x`

I changed to `const privateKey = '0xa0b1c2...'` and it worked.

Hope this helps whoever visits this page.